# grunt-browserify Path must be a string error

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, browserify, grunt-browserify

I'm trying to run `grunt-browserify`. I keep getting the "path must be a string" error.

Here's my `browserify` task:

```
browserify: {
    dist: {
        files: {
            "build/Hotspot.js" : ["lib/**/*.js"]
        },
        options: {
            transform: ["babelify", {
                presets: "es2015"
            }]
        }
    }
},
```

This returns a `Path must be a string` error. However, if I change `files` to

`"build/Hotspot.js" : ["/lib/**/*.js"]`

the task runs, but none of the code seems to be transpiled or bundled. `build/Hotspot.js` is just the standard browserify error handling and nothing else.

Is there something I've done wrong in setting up my `Gruntfile`?

edit 1: I should note that `lib/` exists and has files in it. Also, `"./lib/**/*.js"` yields the same error.

Answer (score 1):

I think the clue to the solution is in the [grunt-browserify docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-browserify), specifically:

> Transforms can also be provided with an options hash; in this case,
>   the transform should be specified as an array of [transformStringOrFn,
>   optionsHash].

I think this is telling us that in order to pass the options hash to a transform, the `options.tranform` value must be an array of arrays:

```
transform: [
    ["babelify", { presets: "es2015" }]
]
```

Comment: Strange error message which suggests completely different, but your assumption helped me today... +1